# google script forms ListItem: how to set pageBreakItems for each choice?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a question about how to set a list of choices in a Google Forms `ListItem` which specifies not only the the choice value but also the `goToPage()` `pageBreak` destination according to the chosen value.

I am sorry for the length of the question: I prefer to give some background to make the issue clear. Thank you so much in advance!

The context is that of a greenhouse in which different actions have to be performed for each plant at different stages of the plant growth, such as sowing, transplanting, harvesting.

The plant name and their stage of growth are stored in a sheet, called plantProgress, which has this form:

```
|plantNumber    |   nextAction |
| ------------- -------------  |
|salad001       |   harvest    |            
|salad002       |   transplant |
|salad003       |   sow        |
```

The `plantNumber` is updated when a new one is created (I have a `pageBreakItem` for this) while the `nextAction` value is updated in the sheet once the previous action has been completed.

When the user opens the form, he is presented with a `ListItem` of the `plantNumber`. Each of the `nextAction` corresponds to a different page (i.e. `pageBreakItem`)

Note that I already created in the Google Forms GUI both the initial page with the `ListItem` and the subsequent `pageBreakItems` with the values of nextAction, so I access to the `ListItem` by its ID, e.g.

```
plantList = form.getItemById("999999999").asListItem()
```

I know how to dynamically create the list of choices values if a new plant is added: I create an array from the `plantNumber` column (e.g. `plantChoices`) and pass it to `plantList`:

```
plantList.setChoiceValues(plantChoices)
```

What I would need to do is to also pass the destination `pageBreakItem` (e.g. harvest) for each choice.

I tried to understand how to do this out by looking at the documentation for the [class `Choice`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice) but I couldn’t figure it out.
Ideally I would like to do something like:

```
plantList = form.getItemById("999999999").asListItem()

plantList.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('salad001', FormApp.PageNavigationType.goToPage("harvest"))
        item.createChoice('salad002', FormApp.PageNavigationType.goToPage("transplant"))
        item.createChoice('salad003', FormApp.PageNavigationType.goToPage("sow"))
      ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue! I just needed to get the id of each defined `pageBreakItem` (sow, transplant, harvest) and pass it to `plantList.createChoice` as a second argument. Here's an example:

```
plantList = form.getItemById("999999999").asListItem()

 sowPage = form.getItemById("111111111").asPageBreakItem();
 transplantPage = form.getItemById("222222222").asPageBreakItem();
 harvestPage = form.getItemById("333333333").asPageBreakItem();


plantList.setChoices([
        plantList.createChoice('salad001', harvestPage),
        plantList.createChoice('salad002', transplantPage),
        plantList.createChoice('salad003', sowPage)
      ])
```